# How can I connect my Xbox 360 to Xbox Live through my Laptop?

Tags: technical-issues, wifi, xbox-360

What steps do I need to do in order to connect my Xbox to Xbox Live through my laptop? I can connect them physically, but I also have a wireless adapter (if it's possible to create a bridge using the adapter as well).

The problem is that I am in an hotel for the next two months, forced to live off their wi-fi. And although my laptop connects to it without a problem, my Xbox 360, even though it has a wireless adapter, does not. It also doesn't present a very helpful error messages, helping me locate the problem. So I'm thinking that connecting the Xbox through my laptop is probably my only hope.

Comment: What operating system do you have on the laptop?

Comment: The hotel wireless probably has a confirmation page of somesort on first loading their service. These sorts of things tend to trip up cheap/stupid wireless accessories like the dongle you'd buy for your X360.

Comment: I'm using Windows XP. And the hotel wireless don't have a confirmation page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [link on Networking](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/connecting/wireless) with the Xbox 360, from xbox.com.

Here are a [couple](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-your-laptop-as-an-XboxXbox-360-wireless-adap/) of [links](http://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-your-Xbox-360-online-using-your-laptop-Si/) from instructables.com that seem to cover exactly what you're trying to do.

And here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpBOnPB1jMU) of the same thing.

Comment: I was about to post the same instructables.com link; it also worked for me. If you need additional help, check out this [Google search for "use laptop as xbox wireless adapter"](http://www.google.com/search?q=use+laptop+as+xbox+wireless+adapter).

Comment: gkrogers - There's a lot of 'fluff' in most of these guides that I would be happy to see removed (you can probably edit everything into a single answer here, explaining about the 'bridge connections' option, and it will be a lot more helpful to people searching for this question in Google). But it still helped me achieve what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @idan315: Yes, I think you're right - it would be very worthwhile doing that and posting the response here as the canonical answer, for future reference. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader... :-)

Comment: You wouldn't be able to accept it now, but answering your own question and getting a score of at least 3 gets you a badge! :-)