# Cheapest way to get Xbox 360 online wirelessly

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 and am looking to move it far enough away from my router that plugging it in with a LAN cable isn't really feasible anymore.

What's the cheapest way for me to get it online wirelessly? The wireless adaptors for Xbox strike me as being ridiculously expensive for what they are. (Upwards of $60 in most cases.)

I have a media center PC that is running on wireless right next to the Xbox, that I could chain off of, but I saw in a few searches that people were saying that messed up their Xboxes.

My other option is probably some kind of wireless bridge.

What's my best bet for this?

Comment: Could be worth looking into power-line networking, if your Xbox and router are both on the same floor then they're likely to be on the same power ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW, here's the [little wireless adapter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=tew+647ga&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&oe=UTF-8&rlz=1I7SNNT&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=4386059849184973727&ei=MpG4TO2nPMmnnQe7tJSyDQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CD4Q8wIwAg#) that's been working for us for about a year - a little cheaper, easy to set up, no hassles.  Not sure I'd have the patience to boot & attach the laptop every time I wanted to use the xbox.

Comment: +1: First I've heard of this.  I'm considering getting one now...

Comment: I was just looking at one of those.  Awesome to hear they work!

Comment: Update on this. Got the little wireless adapter from the link in this answer, and it works great! You'd never know I was running through another device to connect to Live.  Thanks again for the info Kara!

Comment: Glad I could spread some non-proprietary joy. ;)

Comment: Your link is dead, should be changed to a new one if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this for free. Follow the instructions here:

- [How can I connect my Xbox 360 to Xbox Live through my Laptop?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8028/how-can-i-connect-my-xbox-360-to-xbox-live-through-my-laptop)

The instructions are for how to use a wifi laptop as a wireless adapter for the XBox, but they should work for your media center PC as well.

Comment: +1 This is what I was going to suggest (although didn't have a link for).  I'm fortunate that I don't have to worry about that, but I have a friend that does this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically nailed your two best options: wireless bridge, or XBox adapter.

If you do a lot of multiplayer gaming online it might be more worth it just to buy a lot of cable and run a wired connection to your XBox -- I bought the wireless adapter, and I'm not entirely happy with the reception.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. Placing your router near the Xbox, and connecting the other computers in your house to your router via Wireless connection. PC wireless connection is simply cheaper, easier and more reliable than any of the other options listed.
2. Wireless bridge - I've asked about this myself over [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8028/how-can-i-connect-my-xbox-360-to-xbox-live-through-my-laptop). It's way easier than it originally seemed to be. The problem, though, is that you'll sacrifice your PC's wireless connection your console's sake (at least if that computer uses windows XP), and your PC will no longer be able to connect to the network.
3. And... yes, there's the option of the Xbox wifi adapter. You can probably buy one of the older ones (the white adapters) for cheap on ebay, but it's less reliable and more expensive than the two other options.

Answer (score 0):

These are cool. Works for me. Found it a Pc store for $50AU or around that.
It's 3g router, can extend a wifi hotspot, can be plugged into a lan and share that wirelessly, or plug the Xbox into it and connect it to your wifi to share the connection.
[image: TP-Link 3G router]
<sub>(source: [techulator.com](http://www.techulator.com/attachments/Resources/8182-21247-Best-Pocket-WiFi-Router.jpg))</sub>
That's the switch on the side.